# Generate html coverage report in Adonis

Tags: testing, adonis.js

Good afternoon, how are you guys?
Thanking you already
I’m new yet not adonis and following this topic to generate a test report coverage file for this project
project ->https://github.com/Yuri-Tiofilo/adonisTdd 1, and adding the file .nycrc to the project’s root folder and running the adonis test command it doesn’t generate this report.
is there any configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the reports goto to your package.json file where you have

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "node ace test"
  },
```

replace it with

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "nyc node ace test"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Cool, thank you very much, @Onwubiko Chibuike, make and replace and add nyc modules and it worked, I will leave the steps here, for future interested
1. install module nyc 

 `yarn add nyc` or `npm i nyc`

 
2º - replace package.json

```
"scripts": { "start": "node server.js", "test": "nyc node ace test" },
```

3º - create file in base file project **.nycrc**

```
{
  "all": true,
  "include": ["app/**"],
  "reporter": "html",
  "report-dir": "test/coverage"
}
```

4º - run comand 


`npm test`

---

work's for me, Thx.